# Mongodb Intersection of array with list of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, intersection

I will explain the exact use case

I have an array lets say `ratings = [1,2,3,4]`
and I have a MongoDB record

```
  {
    "_id": "1232123",
    "data": [
      {
        "rating": 1,
        "reviewed_on": "datetime"
      },
      {
        "rating": 5,
        "reviewed_on": "datetime"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Something like above. So I want to fetch those records which filter the records in data field whose ratings matches the given array and return the records whose rating matches with the one in the array

Expected output:

```
{"_id": '1232123', "data": [{"rating": 1, "reviewed_on": "datetime"}]}
```

One of the approaches I could think of is to fetch all the results and then filter it on the application level but the set is large so I was assuming to handle it on the db level.

Let me know if the question is not clear and if you want me to add any specific data. Thanks

Comment: Is that document structure correct, specifically `data` property? Its an array of documents with `rating` and `reviewed_on` fields right?.. Please show what u have tried so far.

Comment: @ambianBeing sorry for the trouble i have edited the structure please have a look

Comment: No worries :) [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation pipe with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) as conditional, is what you are looking for. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways youcan do this, I show one way using `filter`

```
[{
    $match: {
        _id: "1232123"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        data: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                cond: {
                    $in: ["$$this.rating", [1, 2, 3, 4]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vaw7lLJke7E)